# Exponentiation of $(x-h)$ divides $f$ if $h$ is a root

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let *F* be a Field. $f \in F[X] \text{ and } h\in F$.
Show that $(x-h)^n|f\text{ if and only if }f(h)=f'(h)=...=f^{n-1}(h)=0$

I want to prove it using $f(h)=0 \Leftrightarrow (x-h)|f$ which i already managed to prove. My Idea was to prove it via induction. The base case for n=1 is easily shown using what i stated above. But i have problems with the induction step.

Comment: False in general. $(x-1)^2$ doesn't divide $x^2-x$ in $\mathbb F_2[X]$ ($\mathbb F_2$ - the field with two elements)

Comment: @Wojowu That's not a counterexample, since the derivative of $x^2-x$ (which is $-1$) evaluated at $h=1$ does not vanish.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Right now, it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: @GregMartin woops, you are right... the example I should have given is $(x-1)^3$ not dividing $x^2-1$ ($=(x-1)^2$). At any rate, it's not true in general.

Comment: To explain @Wojowu's objection. With $f(x)=x^2+1\in\Bbb{F}_2[x]$ we have $f'(x)=0$ and similarly for all the higher derivatives. Yet $x=1$ only has multiplicity two as a zero. For the result to hold you need to assume that $F$ has characteristic zero. Then you can take advantage of the usual formula for the derivative of the product as well as the fact that $D^n(x-h)^n=n!$, a non-zero constant.